# Cross strikethrough text in swift

Tags: swift, nsattributedstring, strikethrough

I need Strikethrough text in swift, I have done this with `NSMutableAttributedString` but strike shows horizontally. But I need that cross like 
[image]

My code:

```
let attributeString: NSMutableAttributedString =  NSMutableAttributedString(string: textLabel.text!)
            attributeString.addAttribute(NSStrikethroughStyleAttributeName, value: 1, range: NSMakeRange(0, attributeString.length))
            attributeString.addAttribute(NSStrikethroughColorAttributeName, value: colors.kSkyColor, range: NSMakeRange(0, attributeString.length))
            textLabel.attributedText = attributeString
```

Comment: There is no such thing feasible with `NSAttributedString` is CocoaTouch.
Now, what's your kind of object? Are they just labels? If there are two consecutive words like "hello world", are they singularly stroked? You can achieve this by doing quite work with CoreText.

Comment: Use UIImage above label with transparent background